# Confusion about change of reference frame in kinematics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames

[image]

$$1.(R_{B/A})_{/A} = (R_{B/A})_{/O}$$

$$2.(\frac{dR_{B/A}}{dt})_{/O} = (\frac{dR_{B/A}}{dt})_{/P} + w_{/O} \times (R_{B/A})_{/A}$$

If $1$ is right , then, $2$ becomes:

$$(\frac{dR_{B/A}}{dt})_{/O} = (\frac{dR_{B/A}}{dt})_{/P} + w_{/O} \times (R_{B/A})_{/A}$$

My question is:

Can I claim that a displacement vector doesn't change according to reference frame once the start point and end point is defined. In the example of picture, I am not sure if the first equation is right. I have learnt from the kinematics that the second equation is right. So if the first equation is right, I can substitute the last term of second equation with the same displacement vector but in another reference frame.

So basically, according to my understanding, reference frame is indifferent to displacement vector once the start point and the end point are defined (my first equation). But for the velocity vector the reference frame does matter even if the start point and end point are defined (my second equation).
Am I right?

Comment: If you're in the frame of the object moving with the object, the object's displacement vector is 0. It depends on the frame of reference.

Comment: @netflix_and_physics sure, the coordinates value depends on the frame of reference. But for example, a*i+b*j = c*I+d*J where i,j,I,J are all unit vectors. a,b are different to c,d. But this equation is still right since i can be expressed by I and J, same case for j.